# Batch Script excueting unchosen block of code

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that checks the input of the user before running a specific block of code. Both blocks manipulate the same variables but it appears the variables of the second block are the ones that are being set even if I choose the first block to execute.

Code:

```
if %x == 1 goto :Block1
if %x == 2 goto :Block2

:Block1
set variable== "Works"

:Block2
set variable == "Works"
```

Block 2 is executing even if I input 1.  Am I missing something?

Comment: `%x%` accesses the current value of `x`, not `%x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike many languages, batch has no concept of the end of a "procedure" - it simply continues execution line-by-line until it reaches the end-of-file. Consequently, you need to `goto :eof` after completing the mainline, otherwise execution will continue through the subroutine code. `:EOF` is a predefined label understood by `CMD` to mean `end of file`. The colon is **required**.